# Angular project build with higher version of clarity ie 4 , can it be included in a platform package.json which uses lower version of clarity ie 1.3

Tags: angularjs, angular, vmware-clarity

we want to build a project A with the latest version of clarity and project  needs to be used in platform B build with angular 7 and clarity version 1.3 as a library inside B. can these be achieved

Answer (score 0):

In generally, this is not likely to work well. This is more due to the way that the TypeScript and Angular compiler works than Clarity, because the Angular versions used are different enough that they do not work together. You can try, but I would recommend updating your old project as it is out of support for Angular at this point.